# How to stop nautilus managing desktop

Tags: nautilus, kde

How can I stop nautilus creating a desktop when it is run in KDE environment. Is there a way to make `nautilus` command work the same as `nautilus --no-desktop`?

I downloaded [Tweak Tool](https://askubuntu.com/a/67332/126106). It has no option for stopping nautlius.

[gconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/a/90856/126106) did not help.

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: @sbergeron:  Is there a way to make `nautilus` command work the same as `nautilus --no-desktop`?

Comment: if you're talking about directly linking a main command to a modifier, you're asking for big trouble come time you want to launch it normally, as the desktop environment triggers the main command, and would prohibit you from launching it normally. Also, I don't think it is really supported without hand-modifying the code for nautilus so the trigger is the same

Comment: How can I change KDE so it always opens nautilus with `--no-desktop` option?

Comment: if you are talking about adding a shortcut, simply add one and then edit the target to include the command

Comment: I'm not talk about a single shortcut. I'm talking about all existing shortcuts in KDE!

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Did you try out [the solution I linked to above](http://askubuntu.com/a/237984/81372)?

Comment: @Glutanimate: Seems working.

Answer (score 1):

This seems working:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```